# file_get_contents not working on url with hashtag symbol in it

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents

I have url which I want to parse:

http://www.ntvplus.ru/tv/#genre=all&channel=3385&channel=3384&channel=3416&date=22.02.2016&date=23.02.2016&date=24.02.2016&date=25.02.2016&time=day

I tried using both file_get_contents and CURL, but they both seem to only send request to `http://www.ntvplus.ru/tv/` and ignore everything after hash symbol.
I tried escaping it but still no luck.
Can someone please provide working solution on this?

Comment: you have to pass the parameters to URL by using curl post then get the response from another end.

Comment: Try this url http://www.ntvplus.ru/tv/schedule.xl?genre=all&channel=3385&channel=3384&channel=3416&date=22.02.2016&date=23.02.2016&date=24.02.2016&date=25.02.2016&time=day

Comment: @brevis that is the last restort, i want to get the html version if somehow possible

Comment: May this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252522/file-get-contents-with-hash-information-included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` elements are client-side only. They won't be parsed with a headless request such as `file_get_contents()` (or even cURL).

As @brevis has suggested in the comments, you have to use the query string version:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.ntvplus.ru/tv/?genre=all&channel=3385&channel=3384&channel=3416&date=22.02.2016&date=23.02.2016&date=24.02.2016&date=25.02.2016&time=day');
```

Comment: To expand a bit on that, it's the client-side Javascript which looks at everything after the `#` and does "stuff" to change the HTML (change layout, load in AJAX, whatever). So doing this would require a full-blown JavaScript interpreter with DOM (i.e. a web browser).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yeah, which is what *they won't be parsed with a headless request* means haha.

Comment: Did you expect the author of this question to understand what exactly that implies? I don't think that two words such as "headless request" fully explains the fault in his assumptions and thinking if he was sufficiently confused to ask this question (not that my slight expansion does that *fully* either, but at least it makes a basic start).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think that you might have misinterpreted my comment, I didn't mean to sound obtuse; I was merely pointing out the link between your comment and the part of my answer to which it related.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks for explaining what's going on here and BenM thanks for the answer. So, basically, it's impossible for me to parse the html version of this url and I have to use the file that is used to retrieve contents? (http://www.ntvplus.ru/tv/schedule.xl?genre=all&channel=3385&channel=3384&channel=3416&date=22.02.2016&date=23.02.2016&date=24.02.2016&date=25.02.2016&time=day)

Comment: Oops, I read too much in that comment. [Here's some nice music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIcaWHHWgD8&list=RDEfEH9lWDIvo&index=2) that you may or may not enjoy as a way of apology.