# python/django regex and unicode string that contains '#' sign

Tags: python, django

I've this pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)-prod(?P<product_id>[0-9]+).html$', 'product_detail', name='product_detail', )
```

It works fine when I have:

```
"some unicode characters"-prod"some numbers".html
```

but when I have '#' sign in "some unicode characters" it doesn't match. Python/django/re truncates the string to the first character of #

For example, if I had:

```
"some unicode # string"-prod"some numbers".html
```

django will search for match

```
"some unicode "
```

Has anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the hash part of the URL is not in the server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is a special character as it concerns URLs. You shouldn't use it in a URL unless it's literally to indicate an anchor within the page. If you insist on using it, it should be urlencoded (i.e. `%23`) and you *should* even be able to get Django's urlresolver to match the urlencoded version.