# Parsing URL value after '#' in a URL

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a very simple sign on using Microsoft Live Connect, but I'm having problems parsing the returning token. I call this URL:

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=wl.skydrive_update&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FMY_SITE.com%2Fcallback.php`

It takes me to the Microsoft server, logs me in, confirms permissions, and then loads the callback URL correctly, looking like this:

`http://MY_SITE.com/callback.php#access_token=LOTS_OF_STUFF&authentication_token=MORE_STUFF&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=wl.skydrive_update`

Now the question is how do I get these tokens? How am I supposed to parse that? They use a '#' instead of '?'.. so $_GET is empty, $_POST is empty, and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't show anything.

Comment: Post a print_r($_SERVER)

Comment: I looked at it and the arguments are no where in there. Something came to me however, could it be that they do this for security to prevent the server from getting the key (altho I don't see why).. I think I could parse the URL in JavaScript and send it to a second PHP script for parsing.

Comment: had you tried parse_url function?

Answer (score 2):

Normally Browsers doesnt send the values after the hash sign to the server. You can process them with JavaScript on the Client side. 
See: [Why the hash part of the URL is not in the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunate that they return with a hash character which is meant to be handled in the client side. If you really need to parse the values using your server-side script (PHP), you can redirect again using JavaScript. You can try to add a JavaScript code like:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    // redirect if hash is detected
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
      var redirect_hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '?');
      var redirect_location = 'http://' + document.domain + redirect_uri;
      window.location = redirect_location;      
    }
  }
```

Then the query string values can be parsed upon redirection.