# get url after "#" in express.js middleware request

Tags: javascript, url, hash, express, request

I need to get url on server middleware (using express.js). I use `req.url` but when url starts from `/#some/url` req.url returns `/`...

The same with `req.path`..

Is there a way to get url after `#` in express.js?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: There's a good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side

Comment: The #-part is not transferred to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the hash part of the URL not available on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-is-the-hash-part-of-the-url-not-available-on-the-server-side)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**No.** The part of the URL starting with the `#` symbol is never sent to the server.

The `#` symbol in an URL is to introduce the [*fragment identifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This is used to link to a specific part of the page. If a browser loads `/#some/url`, it will effectively load `/`, and skip to the HTML element with `id="some/url"` (if present). The fragment identifier is only relevant to the browser, so it is not sent with the HTTP request.

**What you however *can* do**, is using client side Javascript to read out the value of `window.location.hash` and send it to the server using an XMLHttpRequest. ([See other Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side))

Answer (score 2):

Any path/query param after # (Hash symbol) in URL will be removed by the browser.

This can be handled by a small hack by replacing the hash with an EMPTY string in the script tag of HTML/EJS file which will remove the hash and the entire URL will be passed to the server.

In case of a server side rendered application, applying the above technique in  the 404 will route the redirection back to the valid router.

```
<script>
  const hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash.length > 0 && hash.includes("#/")) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace('#/',''));
  }
</script>
```

---

This worked well in my application. Thanks to my teammates for this fix.

Answer (score -5):

Use the built-in `url` [module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) which is available in Node.js to parse the URL and create a [`urlObject`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects). This will have a `hash` fragment property containing the hash fragment you want.

```
const url = require('url')
const urlObj = url.parse(req.url)
console.log(urlObj.hash) // #some/url
```

Comment: Unless the `#`-part is not transferred to the server.

Comment: I tried in local, I run a url like: over-1000-car-911-white-vin#lala, then in nodejs, 
console.log('req.url ', url.parse(req.url))
console.log('req.originalUrl ', url.parse(req.originalUrl)) and the hash symbol is never read as you say