# In NodeJS, how can I get a parameter slug from a URL with a # in it?

Tags: node.js

Example: http://localhost:8080/watch/abcxyz-145#es-2

I want to get slug after '#'. I try get below code but not.

```
app.get('/watch/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
   var slug = req.params.slug;
   var slugs = slug.split(/[\s-]+/);
}
```

Comment: First off their appears to be a syntax error in your sample, make sure you use a closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: Please update the title to ask a clear question. Ex: In NodeJS, how can I get a parameter slug from a URL with a # in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - You can't.

At least not on the server side. The browser doesn't actually send the string after # to the server. If you need to get that information from the browser to your Node.js/Express server, I would recommend grabbing it via `window.location.hash`, then using query params or including it in your request some other way. Assuming you have access to code on the client side.

[Check out this answer for additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280710/6647539)

If you can't go that route, (no pun intended) you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586300/6647539)
answer for a work around, but again, don't make this harder than it needs to be if it's just a matter of sending the rest of a slug to the server.