# Getting whole query param in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have an endpoint like this:

```
app.post('/sendCode', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body;
});
```

And url like this:

http://localhost:3000/sendCode?code=ABCDEFG%##HIJKLMNOPRS

So when I enter this link in the browser I will trigger the endpoint. This works. However my `code` taken from `req.body` cuts out the second part of the code. So in my endpoint I see only `ABCDEFG%` part, the second is cut off. How can I get whole  `ABCDEFG%##HIJKLMNOPRS`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get url after "#" in express.js middleware request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744003/get-url-after-in-express-js-middleware-request)

Comment: From your url `http://localhost:3000/sendCode?code=ABCDEFG%##HIJKLMNOPRS`, it's looks like `req.query`, not `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser won't send the part of the URL that starts with hash `#` symbol. The information that follows the hash (URL fragment) is intended for Javascript code executed by the client.

More on this topic here: [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)