# Query Params include #, Javascript (Node) errors out

Tags: javascript, node.js

To keep this simple, I am using Firebase Cloud Functions, and when/if I receive a param that contains a #, it doesn't recognize it.

For example: `http://example.net?id=123#456`. if I log the `id`, ill only get 123.

However, if I do something like `http://example.net?id=123456`, everything will be logged.

How can I include the # sign with the string value for `id`?

Better Detail:

URL: http://example.com?item=2019+#157&typeOfListing=sold

If I encode the request query

```
let item = encodeURIComponent(req.query.item);
```

I will get the following:

```
2019%20
```

It is not taking the # with it.

Comment: thats part of the hash of the url. you have to encode it. can you provide exactly the input and outputs and the workings of your code for details?

Comment: @DanielA.White updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `#` is a special character in urls (just like `/`, `:`, `?`, ... are), it's used to denote the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) part of the url. You need to escape it using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) like so:

```
let idParam = encodeURIComponent("123#456");
let url = "http://example.net?id=" + idParam;
```

Comment: This isnt including the # sign.

Comment: @soldfor you are on server side? The query param needs to be encoded on the side that generated the request.

Comment: so if its coming from an app (android, ios), it needs to be encoded on the client.

Comment: @soldfor exactly. the hash generally isn't sent to the server

Comment: @soldfor yes, otherwise [it is never sent to server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280710/9867451). The app that sends the request should encode all special characters in the url before making the request

Comment: or deny them all together... which i probably rather. thanks for the help man.

Comment: @soldfor you're welcome, buddy! Glad I could help :-)