# NodeJS parse URL?

Tags: node.js, url, get

I've an url like this: "http://domain.com/get/token#token_id=3042hab1234h00011h", and I need to get the url and retreive token_id from it.

I was using something like this to get all the path and then split it:

```
app.get('/get/token', function (req, res) { 
    var fullURL = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + req.url;
    console.log(fullURL);
});
```

But the result is:

```
http://domain.com/get/token
```

Any suggestion in how to retreive the token_id or the possibility to match the url and then split it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side).

Comment: so I can get the value of token_id only clientside ?

Comment: Yes, unless you send the value. You should use a query string instead.