# The $_GET at # (example.com/#dfsqf)

Tags: php, get

i want to get url like ( exmaple.com/#!fdqfo )

But when i try it and write the code

```
$urll_hash = var_dump($_GET);
exit;
```

I get only ( exmaple.com/ )

There're an way to get what's after # ?

I think it's stop at #

Comment: The hash/fragment is for the client alone. It's not sent to the server.

Comment: I think what you want is URL rewriting. Check the documentations of your webserver.

Comment: there're other way to get url without $_GET !?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side

Comment: Hash fragment Identifier is part of HTML, not part of HTTP