# Google OAuth code appends extra "#" in response

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

We're having a very strange issue all of a sudden with Google's OAuth protocol. For the past 2 months, we have had working code here, and all of a sudden requests exchanging the authorization code for the access and refresh tokens are failing.

I noticed that on the response for the authorization code, there's an extra `#` appended to the URL as below:

```
http://localhost/?code=[AUTHORIZATION CODE]#
```

Pulling the parameter out results in `[AUTHORIZATION CODE]#` as the code, and passing this in to the token request endpoint causes a failure.

**Removing the `#` from this string fixes the issue. Did Google change something today?** I also noticed that there has supposedly been a spike in login outages since this morning on other sites like [this](https://downdetector.com/status/google). Any insights would be very helpful.

Comment: interesting, I noticed the "#" too; but since the `code` is supposed to be sent to the backend, the browser would strip the fragment before calling the redirect URI; doesn't that happen in your case?

Comment: @HansZ. Ah, may be because I'm using `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to pull out the `code`. I'm using the same code to handle logins with Exchange, Live, 365, and Google (and for some reason Microsoft's callback URLs don't allow custom URL schemes) so I had to do it this way.

Comment: technically your code is incorrect then since it plays the role of the User Agent and should strip the fragment like a regular browser would do...

Comment: @HansZ. Hmm. Anything else it should strip aside from the `#`?

Comment: nope; about the fragment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side