# .htaccess not converting percent encoded hash (#) correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My PHP file looks for a URL parameter `id` such that the URL looks like this:

`www.example.com/player.php?id=player_name`

where player_name is the id. I cleaned up the URLs using .htaccess so the URL looks as such:

`www.example.com/Player/player_name/`

and that has been fine except for in the case that I pass in a player ID such as #octothorpe (encoded as %23octothorpe). For some reason, this is still read as a fragment in the URL and ignored by the server, so when the PHP file looks for `id`, it can't find it. The interesting part is that if I use the ugly URL

`www.example.com/player.php?id=%23octothorpe`

its works completely fine, but when I do

`www.example.com/Player/%23octothorpe`

It can't find `id`

The relevant part of the .htaccess file looks as such:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Player/(.*)/$ player.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^Player/(.*)$ player.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I figured out my problem. The issue was that Apache was decoded my URL when it was converted by htaccess, so I used the [B] flag on my rules such that

`RewriteRule ^Player/(.*)/$ player.php?id=$1`

became

`RewriteRule ^Player/(.*)/$ player.php?id=$1 [B]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that url fragments are not passed to the apache server. Where you have used it in a query string parameter it's not considered a url fragment which is why it works.

[Why the hash part of the URL is not in the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side)

If your id's contain hash characters you will need to think of another strategy for your urls. The solution really depends on the wider context of your application.

Comment: I understand the hash is not sent to the server, but I encoded the hash so that it's passed at %23.