# Angular 2 - Send value with hashtag in url

Tags: javascript, angular

In my application I have a list of registered products.

I am trying to send the product name in the url.

However the product name it has `#` hashtag and the product name is arriving incomplete on the server:

**front end**

```
var product = "PLASTIC #1JQ-M 1CV T-PLAS"
return this._http.get(Config.URL_SITE + 'list/productLen?product='+product)...
```

**back end**

```
router.get('/productLen', function(req, res, next) {
  var productName= req.query.product;
  console.log(productName) //PLASTIC
...
```

How to make the `productName` variable receive the full name? 
`"PLASTIC #1JQ-M 1CV T-PLAS"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function before adding product name to URL.

```
var product = "PLASTIC #1JQ-M 1CV T-PLAS"
return this._http.get(Config.URL_SITE + 'list/productLen?product=' + encodeURIComponent(product))...
```

Everything after hash is stripped off by the browser [Why the hash part of the URL is not in the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side).

There are alternative solutions: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side), but they are mostly how to retrieve hash on server in general.