# How to get full url has # in php

Tags: php

Actually, I do not know how to get url if it has # at the end of URL.

For example, Instagram returns token like this `"http://example.com/#token=abc.123"`

Then how can I get this by PHP?

Thank for your advice.

Comment: You can't. It's not send to the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the hash part of the URL is not in the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side)

Comment: For example if you read this in javascript, and...

Comment: So any way to use jquery/javascript and send it to server later.

Comment: You can read it out with JavaScript and send it with Ajax probably, but that doesn't really sound like a good approach. You might have a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).