# How can I redirect a URL containing a #?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a link that needs to be redirected elsewhere. My CMS (WP Engine) typically handles redirects, however, I am stuck with the following.

(placeholder domain for client privacy)

LINK A: www.test.com/#/contacts

LINK B: www.test.com/another-page

How can I successfully redirect A to B?

Is there any special steps (CMS related or not) that I need to do to make a URL with a hash symbol redirect?

Comment: It is possible to do with JavaScript only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-the-hash-part-of-the-url-is-not-in-the-server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you only want to forward urls with `#`? If it's just one page, you can just string match the current url with the page you want to redirect.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    $current_page = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    if( strpos( $current_page, '/#/contact' ) !== false ){
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/another-page/' ) );
        exit;
    }
});
```

If you have multiple pages, and the permalinks are `/#/slug`, you can use a redirection plugin such as [Content Mask](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-mask/), [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/), or [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/).

Comment: Months later, but that you so much