# NGINX, trying to redirect/rewrite direct one URL to another but ignore args include "#"

Tags: nginx

I am trying to rewrite/redirect a URL to another URL, but when it has a "#" in the arguments, this pulled through and shown in the new URL eg.

https://blah.co.uk/ep/doc/index.jsp#/download
needs to be rewritten to
https://blah.co.uk/Download/?Mode=doc

Now whatever I seem to try I always get the rewritten URL as
https://blah.co.uk/Download/?Mode=doc#/download

it seems to always bring through the "#" and everything after it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hash part or URL (`#/download` in your case) is not requested from the web server at all, so nginx doesn't ever seen it and it can't be a subject of URL rewrites. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-is-the-hash-part-of-the-url-not-available-on-the-server-side) for more details. The hash part of URL is intended for client-side processing only, and the only way to get rid of it, AFAIK, is to use some client-side JavaScript, for example:

```
if (window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('', '/', window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```