# Angular HttpClient get request URL removes hashtag/number sign

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm using httpclient get, when I have a `#` in the request URL it removes everything after the `#`

Example:

**Intended Request:**

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1#TEST`

**Actual Request:**

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`

I tried using PathLocationStrategy, but its only effecting router links.

Made a slackblitz example, it has the PathLocationStrategy also.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-p5yrdq

[image]

1. Why does this happen?
2. Any solutions/workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-is-the-hash-part-of-the-url-not-available-on-the-server-side

Comment: it's a fragment.. not part of the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to intercept and encode the url and parameters.

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
```

**EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const params = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomEncoder(), fromString: req.params.toString()});
    const httpUrlEncoding = new HttpUrlEncodingCodec();
    return next.handle(req.clone({
      params,
      url: httpUrlEncoding.encodeValue(req.url),
    }));
  }
}
```

**CustomEncoder**

```
export class CustomEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```