# Hashtag not passing by Angular HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpclient

I need to call rest api for example:

```
let developerId ="123#212";
let url = `${Constants.BASE_URL}${marketId}/developers/${developerId}`;
return this.http.get(url);
```

But backend only getting `123` instead of `123#212`

What I tried so far is to do but not working

- Using encodeURIComponent
  `encodeURIComponent(${developerId})`
- Using `HttpInterceptor`
  same with https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524089

Calling the rest api using Postman perfectly working but not in Angular

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664324/4365927

Comment: Why postman able to call this kind of rest api and angular not able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending this with hashtag use `HttpParams` to send this data you can see the same being used in the question you mentioned.

In your post/get request you can add this

```
this.http.get('URL', {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('param-a', 'value-1')
        .set('param-2', 5)
    })
```

Comment: HttpParams is for query parameter right? But the hastag is part of URL not query parameter

Comment: Yes but when you want to send data to backend it should be sent using Params or Headers, also looks like # data is for browsers only & even if you encode you would still need to send it as a param or it would just act as a different URL. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664324/1731150