# How to call API in JavaScript with # symbol in URI?

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I want to call a REST API from JavaScript.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var mainURI = '<MyAPIURI>';
var mainURIEncoded = encodeURI(mainURI);

var mainRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
mainRequest.open('GET', mainURIEncoded, true)

mainRequest.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
}
```

I get this error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'MyAPIURI(Cut off at '#')'

My URI has a '#' symbol in it and it seems like the problem is my `mainURIEncoded` string is cut off at the '#'.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out what the ascii encoding for it might be like how space is `&nbsp`?

Comment: `encodeURI()` does not alter the `#` character.

Comment: the hash is not sent to the server. it is only a client side representation.

Comment: Seems like a good ole' case of a 404. Sure your URL is good?

Comment: @Chris Neve Yes I'm sure. I don't know the encoding for '#' and I couldn't find a straight up easy google answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the hash part of the URL not available on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-is-the-hash-part-of-the-url-not-available-on-the-server-side)

Comment: I've debugged it and in the error displayed it definitely cuts off at the '#'.

Comment: Generally, you should not `encodeURI()` the entire URL. You should use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode parameter values. In your case, assuming your URL is "http://myhost/api/action?action=#someParam", it's only the `#someParam` action that needs to be encoded. Show your actual URL so we can provide more info.

Comment: @Cid I've replaced all '#' with %23 and now it works :D.

Comment: Why didn't the encodeURI() change my '#' to '%23'?

Comment: In URI syntax, the `#` marks the beginning of a fragment that should *not* be sent to the server. It's handled by the browser. If you want the `#` to be part of something sent to the server, you have to encode the URI piece-by-piece with `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to replace all '#' with '%23' after using `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`.

Refer to the helpful comments on the question.