# Azure is blocking my angular.js routes (works on Aws & GCP)

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-vm

So I have this Angularjs (not newer angular) thats been running on Gcp and I am trying to migrate it to Azure. Right now I am testing it on an Azure VM but somehow some routes are working while others are not working. I am guessing that something is blocking the URLs and I need help figuring what that setting is. The app works on GCP and Aws without any issues.

URLs/route format that work : #something
URLs/route format that don't work : #something@somethingelse

I am suspecting that its a security issue with URLs.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: Can you give more details on the server? What kind of VM is it? Is there an Application Gateway / Frontdoor in front of it (or something else)?

Comment: @juunas Ubuntu serve 20.04LTS Gen2, selected standard security option. Didnt do much else except open HTTP(port 80 tcp) and HTTPS(port 443 tcp) which were initially closed. And has a public ip

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? [The hash part of the URL is not really sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664324/10417839), so I don't see how this could be blocked.