# Problem with hashtag (#) character in httpclient and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, dotnet-httpclient

I have a problem using httpClient and WCF, in particular when I put a hashtag (#) as input.
Here below my code:

for WCF:

```cs
[OperationContract]
[WebGet( RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetCase/{*id}" )]
string[] GetCase( string id );
```

on client:

```cs
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseProxy = false;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
string link = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}/", host, port);
Uri url = new Uri(link);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(link);
string serviceName = "Service";
string restPart = "rest";
string method = "GetCase";
string valueToSearch = Uri.EscapeDataString("TEST#12345");
string completeLinkWithMethod = link + serviceName + "/" + restPart + "/" + method;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = await client.GetAsync(completeLinkWithMethod + "/" + valueToSearch);
```

When I make a call, on client I see that `valueToSearch` is "*TEST%2312345*" but when I go on server, id value is "*TEST*"

Is there a way to pass all the string without it has been truncated?

When I make a call, on client I see that valueToSearch is "*TEST%2312345*" but when I go on server, id value is "*TEST*"

Is there a way to pass all the string without it has been truncated?

Comment: Have you tried without using EscapeDataString?  
`string valueToSearch = "TEST#12345";`

Comment: Yes, same problem

Comment: Are `valueToSearch` and `valToSearch` the same? In other words is `valToSearch` a typo?

Comment: BTW are you aware of the fact that `#` has a special meaning in case of URL? It separates the query string part from the [fragment string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733187/13268855) part.

Comment: Yeah sorry they are the same... I know that it means part from fragment string but I need it because the id is a free field and operator can put whatever he want

Comment: **#** represents the fragment identifier in the URL, but if you want to pass the actual **#** character in the URL, you need to encode it to **%23**. This explains that "TEST#12345" becomes "TEST%2312345". On the server it should process the "%2312345" together. But in the end, no matching results were found. So you can consider modifying the string format.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most stacks (including .net) do not send the fragment (#) to the server, they are a client only thing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment#:~:text=When%20an%20agent%20(such%20as,does%20not%20send%20the%20fragment.

To work around this, you'll need to duplicate or move whatever you need from the fragment into something that goes to the server.  For instance the query string.

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome this limitation is that you perform custom string encoding on both-side. For example:

```
var encodedHashtag = $"U+{Char.ConvertToUtf32("""#""", 0)}";
var valueToSearch = "TEST#12345".Replace("#", encodedHashtag);
```

and

```
var encodedHashtag = $"U+{Char.ConvertToUtf32("""#""", 0)}";
var decodedId = id.Replace(encodedHashtag, "#");
```

Please bear in mind that if the user enters a case id, which included `U+35` then this approach will not work as intended.